I-Series RPGLE function to test multiple bits in array for a value
I'm trying to determine if there's a more efficient coding technique I can use for an if statement.  I have a bit array that can contain 128 bits, either 0 or 1. Currently, my code looks like this:
if bi(64)='1' or bi(66)='1' or bi(67)='1' or bi(68)='1'
or bi(69)='1' or bi(70)='1' or bi(71)='1' or bi(72)='1'
or bi(73)='1' or bi(74)='1' or bi(75)='1' or bi(76)='1'
or bi(77)='1' or bi(78)='1' or bi(79)='1' or bi(80)='1'
or bi(81)='1';                                         

Obviously this doesn't work, but is there a method I could use to simplify this expression like this or something?
if bi(64) or bi(65) or bi(66) or bi(67) = '1'; 

I have actually tried the statement above, but the compiler doesn't like it.

What did you mean when you said "Obviously this doesn't work"? The %scan and %subarr solutions are different ways of doing the same thing, but they won't work if your long "IF" statement doesn't work.
If they really are bits, with 8 bits in every byte, then it would be good to show us how you defined the variable you're checking.

Something like this should work:
if %scan('1' : bi(64) + bi(65) + bi(66) + bi(67)) > 0;

See the %SCAN function for more information.

Thanks, I didn't even think about the %scan although I use it all the time.  Another excuse for a vacation I guess!

You don't include your definitions, but I assume that "bit array" really means "indicator array".
dcl-s bi ind dim(128);

You also don't mention how/why you're picking the elements you've shown.  Assuming it's always a contiguous range, the %SUBARR built-in function may be of use.  And if you are on a supported version of the OS the IN operator makes this easy.
// note this is 64-81, did you mean to leave 65 out of your example? 
if '1' in %subarr(bi:64:18);
  dsply 'at least one on';
else;
  dsply 'all off';
endif;  


Sorry.  I am so used my field I forget how to explain things sometimes.  Basically I'm working  in an ISO8583 world, and as one example, we will say this is MasterCard.  ISO8583 has 2 bit maps 64 bits each which I have in a string.  I'm basically working on a display file that maps the detailed MasterCard (or any ISO msg) into a display file.  So basically, I'm mapping a message and as an example, if screen 7 displays bits 52-60, and there's no data for 52-60, I want to skip those bits.  So in my array if bi(52)-bi(60) is all set to zero, I skip displaying that screen.

Thanks, that looks like an interesting function.  I'll try that on Monday and check it out.  Field 65 is left out because ISO8583 doesn't contain a field 65 even though the bit is present.  However, this bit will always be off so it's safe to include in that search.

The RPGLE compiler doesn't recognize the "IN" keyword, so I'm not able to compile this one.  Playing around with it, I tried if %scan('1':%subarr(bi:41:6)) > 0;  It feels like that should work also, but it doesn't.  Seems like the %scan function is the only way to go at the moment.  :(

@DarrenB what version of the OS are you on?  Should work on 7.3+ with current PTFs.  Also rather than trying to deal with bitmaps in RPG, have you considered building a function in C/C++ to translate into something RPG can easily deal with?  The great thing about ILE is it's interoperability.

we are at 7.4.  This code was done back around the V3 days, and I'm just tasked with converting old RPGIII code to RPGIV & free where I can, and am just trying to eliminate unnecessary code where I can.  I'm not quite ready to start trying to get C/C++ involved in the mix.  :)

RPG doesn't have bit arrays, but it does have character arrays and bit functions. You can write a subprocedure to make something like your proposed syntax workable.
dcl-proc bitSet;
  dcl-pi *n ind;
    bitarr128    char(16);
    ix           int(10);
  end-pi;

  dcl-ds bitarrds;
    bitarr   char(1) dim(16);
  end-ds;
  dcl-ds maskds;
    *n        char(1) inz(x'80');
    *n        char(1) inz(x'40');
    *n        char(1) inz(x'20');
    *n        char(1) inz(x'10');
    *n        char(1) inz(x'08');
    *n        char(1) inz(x'04');
    *n        char(1) inz(x'02');
    *n        char(1) inz(x'01');
    mask      char(1) dim(8) pos(1);
  end-ds;
  dcl-s arrayix    int(10);
  dcl-s maskix     int(10);

  bitarrds = bitarr128;
  arrayix = ((ix-1)/8)+1;
  maskix = %rem((ix-1):8)+1;
  return %bitand(bitarr(arrayix): mask(maskix)) <> x'00';
end-proc;

Then use the function like this
if bitSet(bi:61) or bitSet(bi:62) or bitSet(bi:63) or
   bitSet(bi:64) or bitSet(bi:65) or bitSet(bi:66);

You would have to make sure you didn't pass an out of bounds index, or with a little extra work you could add some exception handling, or even make the function generic enough to handle variable size bit arrays.

Unfortunately, RPG does not support bitmaps.
We can declare an array of "indicators", but each element of the array will occupy one byte with the boolean value *on (character '1' ) or *off (character '0' )
To work with bits in RPGs there are BIFs - %bitand / %bitnot / %bitor / %bitxor - see how suitable they may be for your purposes.

It might work out like this:
128 bits is 16 bytes. Let's assume that the bits are numbered from left to right, starting from 1st to 128th.
Then
  Bit  Byte    M1    M2
  1-8     1  0x00  0x00
  9-16    2  0x00  0x00
 17-24    3  0x00  0x00
 25-32    4  0x00  0x00
 33-40    5  0x00  0x00
 41-48    6  0x00  0x00
 49-56    7  0x00  0x00
 57-64    8  0x01  0x01
 65-72    9  0x7F  0xE0
 73-80   10  0xFF  0x00
 81-88   11  0x80  0x00
 89-96   12  0x00  0x00
 97-104  13  0x00  0x00
105-112  14  0x00  0x00
113-120  15  0x00  0x00
121-128  16  0x00  0x00

M1 set of bytes for the condition
if bi(64)='1' or bi(66)='1' or bi(67)='1' or bi(68)='1'
or bi(69)='1' or bi(70)='1' or bi(71)='1' or bi(72)='1'
or bi(73)='1' or bi(74)='1' or bi(75)='1' or bi(76)='1'
or bi(77)='1' or bi(78)='1' or bi(79)='1' or bi(80)='1'
or bi(81)='1';

and M2 - for the condition
if bi(64) or bi(65) or bi(66) or bi(67) = '1';

define
dcl-c bitMask1   const(x'00000000000000017FFF800000000000');
dcl-c bitMack2   const(x'0000000000000001E000000000000000');

dcl-s bitArr128  char(16);

where bitArr128 is the bit array to be checked.
Then the first condition will be written in the form
if %bitand(bitArr128: bitMask1) <> 0;

and the second - in the form
if %bitand(bitArr128: bitMask2) <> 0;

I’ll say right away that I haven’t tested it myself (personally, it would be easier for me to write such a function in C and include it as a separate module in the RPG program). But try it - it might work.
Naturally, for each check you will need to determine the required bit mask
